# Substitution for unknown true density in 'Density Estimation Trees'

Tags: density-function, loss-functions, density-estimation

I'm having a hard time understanding parts of the derivation of the objective function for [Density Estimation Trees](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2020507) (reference below) regarding the loss function.

Taken from the article (Sec. 3.1):

> Definition 1. The piecewise constant density estimate of the decision
>   tree $T$ built on a set $S$ of $N$ observations in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is defined as
>   $$\hat{f}_N(x) = \sum_{l\in\tilde{T}}^{} \frac{|l|}{NV_l}
> > \mathbb{I}(x\in l)$$
>   where $\tilde{T}$ is the set of leaves of the decision tree $T$ representing
>   the partitions of the data space, $|l |$ is the number of observations
>   of $S$ in the leaf $l$ , $V_l$ is the volume of the leaf $l$ within the $d$
>   dimensional bounding box of $S$ and $\mathbb{I}(·)$ is the indicator function.
>   A decision tree $T$ requires a notion of a loss function $R(T )$
>   which is minimized using a greedy algorithm to construct a
>   tree on the set of observations.For the unsupervised task of
>   density estimation, we consider the Integrated Squared Error (ISE) loss function [10]. [...]

They continue introducing the optimization problem of such a tree as

$$ \min_{\hat{f}_N \in \mathcal{F_N}} \int_X \left(\hat{f}_N(x) - f(x) \right)^2dx$$

where $\hat{f}_N(x)$ is the density estimate of the model at hand for $x$ and $f(x)$ is the unknown true density.

**What is unclear to me is what exactly is happening with the true density in the following, as I don't understand its substituion:**

> After expanning the square and the following Monte-Carlo substitution
>   $\int_X \hat{f}_N(x) f(x) dx \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{f}_N(X_i)$ (where $\{ {X_i}\}_{i=1}^{N}$
>   is the training set) the objective function in Eq. 2 is replaced by
>   the following consistent plug-in estimator of the ISE*:
>
> $$\min_{\hat{f}_N \in \mathcal{F}_N} \left\{\int_X \left(\hat{f}_N(x)
> > \right)^2 dx - \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{f}_N(X_i)\right\}$$

The true density was subsituted with $\frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{f}_N(X_i)$, so the sum over the models density estimates of the training data multiplied by 2 divided by the number of observations.

**Questions:**

1. Can someone explain the ("Monte-Carlo"?) substitution applied here and why it can be used to replace the true density here?
2. How come that this substitution is possible here, while for example in the context of [bandwidth estimation for KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Bandwidth_selection) this apparently is not possible - I quote the linked section: "*[...].Neither the AMISE nor the hAMISE formulas are able to be used directly since they involve the unknown density function $ƒ$ or its second derivative $ƒ''$* "

(*: they added a footnote here that states "The term $\int_X (f(x))^2dx$ is removed from the objective function since it is independent of the estimate and hence doesn't affect the optimum")

**Reference**

> Ram, P., & Gray, A. G. (2011, August). Density estimation trees. In
>   Proceedings of the 17th ACM SIGKDD international conference on
>   Knowledge discovery and data mining (pp. 627-635). ACM.